# Importing Matrix format ( .mtx) in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I am a transportation planner and work with matrices a lot. I have data in a lot of Matrix file formats (.mtx).

Can anyone please tell me how to import this data in R?

Your help is much appreciated. I have R: 3.6 version.

Comment: A quick search brought up `readMM()` from the `Matrix` package as the first result. [Have you tried that?](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/externalFormats.html)

Comment: Hi Gregor- Unfortunately when installing the package gives me the following error:


`
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/PGupta/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Comment: `Matrix` is installed by default when you install R. Try `library(Matrix)`. Alternatively, if you want to re-install it or update it, follow the link to download and install Rtools first. (Note that Rtools is *not* an R package, but a toolchain for Windows to be able to compile R packages.)

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
Matrix::readMM('file_dir')
```